# Why do we need to check if user is instance of UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've noticed in FOSUserBundle Controllers ([ProfileController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/ProfileController.php)) the check if the `$user` is instance of `UserInteface`

```
$user = $this->getUser();
if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
}
```

Is it enough to check only `if (!is_object($user))`?

If my user entity extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`, in which case `$user` will not be instance of `UserInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if your code isn't meant be open-sourced otherwise no.

Not checking for the object's instance doesn't insure that the object returned by the method `getUser()` will have all the methods you are expecting (example: `getUsername()`).

If you look at the `getUser()` method from [Controller.php](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php) it does not necessarily return a user object. In fact, you could set up Symfony2 firewall in a way that `getUser()` would return a different object of a different instance.

Admitting that we have an interface `UserInterface` which defines `getUsername()`.

In the following code, our User object does not implement `UserInterface`.

```
$user = $this->getUser();
if (!is_object($user)) {
    $user->getUsername();
}
```

This code will throw an error because `getUsername()` does not exist on the object, instead the code should have been the following:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
    $user->getUsername();
}
```

If the user object does not implement the proper interface then the code won't error out because it won't be executed.

Avoid checking the object like the following

```
$user = $this->getUser();
if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof User) {
    $user->getRoles();
}
```

If someone extends the User object then the if statement won't be executed anymore because `$user` will not be an instance of `User` but say `ExtendedUser` even though it has all the methods you need.

The other advantage of using interfaces is that you can implement multiple interfaces on a object.

```
class A implements C {}

class B extends A implements C, D {}

interface C {}

interface D {}

$nA = new A();
$nB = new B();

$nA instanceof A; // true - instance of A
$nA instanceof B; // false - pretty obvious, no relationship with B
$nA instanceof C; // true - A implements C
$nA instanceof D; // false - A does not implement D

$nB instanceof A; // false - B is not an instance of A
$nB instanceof B; // true - instance of B
$nB instanceof C; // true - A implements C, that's the key:
                  //        both A and B implements C but B is not an
                  //        instance of A.
$nB instanceof D; // true - A implements D
```

TLDR; interfaces are a great way to set expectations and avoid major headaches.

When you read through the code you can quickly identify the type of objects that are passed around. If someone changes the code it will either show a meaningful error or it will degrade gracefully (in this case, the user will be denied access).

Answer (score 1):

> If my user entity extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`, in which case `$user` will not be instance of `UserInterface`?

This is not true, as `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` implements `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface`, which extends (interfaces extend other interfaces) `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface` which extends `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`. So `$user instanceof UserInterface` will be true.

An interface is the contract in the object oriented world. With `is_object($user)`, you know the `$user` is an object, but you don't know which public methods the object has, etc. Nothing prevents `$this->getUser()` from returning a completely different object, breaking your code. When you check for the instance, you have a promise: The methods in the interface are available to you. As a rule, I would recommend you to never call methods you didn't either explicitely typehint for or check for using `instanceof`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a bit strange for new and old developers.

the interface allows for multiple inheritance.  I was taught that you use inheritance for when classes are best described as "is a", like dog is an animal or SwiftMailer is a Mailer.

interfaces can then be used to bolt in extra functionality, it acts like a contract that says this class must implement some method.  like bark or mail.  And I was taught that these interfaces should be named things like canBark or Barkable or Mailable etc, these would then implement methods like bark or mail.

but modern dev tends more towards using interfaces as an extra abstraction so you can quickly swap classes around.

so instead of binding to your user class you would bind to the UserInterface which the User class would implement.

so to answer your actual question, as long as either the FOS\UserBundle\Model\User class or your User class implements the UserInterface interface, then you are good to go.

Comment: It's not to quickly swap classes around but to be sure these classes have to required implementation, the required methods, so that the existing code can call upon these when needed and that you don't have to hack their source to meet your own class

Comment: Interfaces DO NOT allow for multiple inheritance, there is no multiple inheritance in php.

Answer (score -1):

Wouter J is right : FOS\UserBundle\Model\User implements FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface but if  you don't append "use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;" in your file then the instanceof test will not pass. Don't forget that.